# How to handle Read Timeout Error when scraping Edmunds.com website in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling, beautifulsoup, nlp, timeout

I am trying a beginner in web scraping, trying to scrape customer reviews from https://www.edmunds.com/ for my research.

However, even the basic code gives only Read Timeout Errors.

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
result = requests.get("https://www.edmunds.com/")
print(result.status_code)
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Hi Juliana, please familiarise yourself with [writing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask your next one! Enjoy your stay here at SO :)

Answer (score 0):

The website has some basic anti-**scraping** mechanism. In particular, it checks that your 'get' request actually resembles one coming from a browser and has a header. If you want to ... get somewhere, see below how to pass a standard header in your request.

Now, i wouldn't use that website to learn **scraping** - most of it look like it's build on javascript (haven't thoroughly checked + you need to assess this depending on the page you target). If you want to **scrape** this site you would either need to find the underlying API calls or you need more advanced tools like selenium that rely on a browser...

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4040.128"
}

result = requests.get("https://www.edmunds.com/", headers=header, timeout=15)
print(result.status_code)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it with the header and request_html but as you said, it does not work because of the anti-scrapping mechanism. How can I work around it using selenium? They had an API available which they closed in 2017.

Answer (score 0):

*Use [requests_html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) Or add `User-Agent` to the headers*

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
url = session.get('https://www.edmunds.com/')

try:
    status = url.status_code
    print(status)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

---

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
}
result = requests.get(url="https://www.edmunds.com", headers=headers)

try:
    status = result.status_code
    print(status)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

*before you start scraping see https://www.edmunds.com/robots.txt*